# System to cope with NAT

Tags: nat

Problem: make 2 workstations (ws) in different sites under the NAT to establish a session.

Description: there are 3 workstations. 1st ws located under NAT in site A (wsA). 2nd ws located under NAT site B (wsB). 3rd ws located in site C, has public ip (wsC)

Question: Is there a solution (to install in the wsC) such that wsC communicates with nodes (wsA,wsB) to make wsA,wsB establish a tunnel, but isn't involved in traffic forwarding.

The traffic goes directly between wsA<--->wsB.

Wishlist: Open source solution, linux support(cent os,ubuntu)

Comment: [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)).

Comment: Tinc supports automatic UDP hole punching. You can set up a three node tinc network with all three machines.

Comment: What you are asking for, “a direct connection between A and B” is not possible. One of the networks must forward ports for this to happen.  After which C will not be, and has not been, needed. Without port forwarding there has to be an intermediary server to transmit data between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) to tunnel through the network; have C act as the server, the others connect to it as clients. I'm not sure how to answer the part about a direct connection between Workstation A and B, although the server on C could provide access between them **as long as they can access C**